# How to get what files have been changed from previous build to this build and who did the changes in subversion

Tags: svn

is it a possible to get the files changed from previous build to the next build and who did the changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the revision numbers of the two builds you can use [`svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re15.html):

```
svn log -r <previous rev>:<next rev>
```

For example:

```
svn log -r 1066:1105
```

Comment: Thanks. But its not listing file names

C:\Final Check out>svn log -r 101:102
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r101 |  ID | 2009-06-12 05:59:11 -0400 (Fri, 12 Jun 2009) | 1 line


------------------------------------------------------------------------
r102 | ID | 2009-06-15 03:47:10 -0400 (Mon, 15 Jun 2009) | 1 line

. Please let me know how to get the file name also

Answer (score 1):

To discover the changes, use

```
svn blame <filename>
```

This will show you who is responsible for which line of code - if you want a specific version, use

```
svn blame <filename>:<rev>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
svn diff --summarize -c 123
```

shows the files that where changed in the changeset 123, i.e. in the commit that turned revision 122 into revision 123.

```
svn log -c 123
```

shows you who made that commit. You can replace

```
-c 123
```

by

```
-r COMMITTED:HEAD
```

to get the last change (this assumes your working copy is up to date; call `svn up` to make sure).